# Is there an algorithm to identify the increasing Period/Interval of a time series?

Tags: time-series, trend

[image: The increasing interval for this time series is located between 2000 and 3000]

Is there an algorithm to identify the increasing interval of a time series? For example, to detect that the increasing interval of this time series is located between the time step 2000 and 3000.